# In processing can you make something happen if a object moves onto a certain color?

Tags: if-statement, processing

Using an if statement can one make a object react to what color is underneath it? For example if I want a moving circle to react in a certain way when it is moving over anything blue. I'm a newbie in processing language.

Comment: Yes, I made the screen light up red when a shape moved over a certain color. Would you like to see the code?

Comment: I asked because this question is marked as unanswered, which means it shows up on the unanswered tab. If you found an answer, you might want to post it as an answer and mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

As always, your best friend is [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Specifically, check out the [`get()`](https://processing.org/reference/get_.html) function, which gives you a color at a specific pixel location. You can call this function on the sketch directly, or on a `PGraphics` or `PImage` instance.

From there it's just a matter of using `if` statements to check the color under a point. I'd recommend [splitting your problem up into multiple steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and approaching each of those steps one at a time. Can you write a program that just prints out the color under a hard-coded point? Then can you write a program that prints out the color under the mouse cursor? Work your way up from there, and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question if you get stuck.